# What are the arguments supplied to ColorFunction in MandelbrotSetPlot?

Tags: plotting, color, options, undocumented, fractals

On the [document of `MandelbrotSetPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MandelbrotSetPlot.html), it said:

> With ColorFunction->f, where f is a function, the argument of f is a real number in proportional to the number of iterates, and f must return color directives, such as RGBColor and Hue, or named colors, such as Red and Blue.

It seems to have only one argument. But an example uses the third argument:

[image]

So I tried evaluating

```
Reap[MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
       ColorFunction -> ((Sow[{##}]; If[#1 == 1, 
                                        Black,
                                        RGBColor[(1 - #3)^2, (1 - #3)^3, 1 - #3]]) &)
       ]
     ]
```

[image]

and noticed that it has exactly five arguments. The first, second and third arguments are real numbers between `0.` and `1.`, while the fourth is an integer and the fifth is a complex number.

I think the third argument is proportional to the number of iterations. What do the other arguments mean?

---

#### Update:

I think Mathematica just calculates the upper half of the Mandelbrot set.

```
Graphics[{PointSize@0, 
  Point[{Re@#, Im@#} & /@ 
    Reap[MandelbrotSetPlot[ColorFunction -> (Sow@#5 &)]][[2, 1]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the statement in docs that: "ColorFunction->"name" is equivalent to ColorFunction->(If[#==1,Black,ColorData["name"][#]]&)." is not true. There should be `#3` not `#`. First and the second arguments are coordinates. Here they are in (0,1) interval because `ColorFunctionScaling` is `True`.

Comment: The fourth argument is 1 if the point is in the Mandelbrot set, and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments by @alephalpha and @Kuba for

```
MandelbrotSetPlot[{xmin + ymin I, xmax + ymax I}, ColorFunction -> (f[#,#2,#3,#4,#5]&)]
```

1. **`Slot #1`** corresponds to the horizontal coordinate `x`.

   - If `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`, then `#1` ranges from `0` to `1` as `x` ranges from `xmin` to `xmax`.
   - If `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, then `#1` ranges from `0` to `1` as `x` ranges from `0` to `1`. The value of `#1` is `0` for `x <= xmin` and is `1` for `x >= xmax`.
2. **`Slot #2`** corresponds to the vertical coordinate `y`.

   - If `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`, then `#2` ranges from `0` to `1` as `y` ranges from `ymin < 0` to `ymax < 0`. However, `#2` ranges from `1` to `0` to `ymax` as `y` ranges from `ymin < 0` to `0` to `ymax > 0`, unless `ymax > -ymin`, plus yet more bizarre conditions ...
   - If `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, then `#2` ranges from `1` to `0` to `1` as `y` ranges from `-1` to `0` to `1`. The value of `#2` is `1` for `y <= ymin` and is `1` for `y >= ymax`.
3. **`Slot #3`** is roughly proportional to the log of the number of iterations.

   - If `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`, then `#3` ranges from `0` and `1`, logarithmically.
   - If `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, then `#3` ranges from `0` to `MaxIterations` (default `100`), logarithmically.
4. **`Slot #4`** is `1` if the point is in the *Mandelbrot* set, and is `0` otherwise.
5. **`Slot #5`** is apparently the final iterated value of complex iterate `z`, whose absolute value exceeds the `EscapeRadius` (default `2`). Although, the magnitude of this `z` is much greater than the escape radius...

Comment: I think `Slot #2` corresponds to the absolute value of the vertical coordinate. The Mandelbrot set is symmetric, so Mathematica might just calculate the upper half.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for that. The Abs may explain the bizarre behaviour. @Kuba: thanks for the edits! I will use them in future.